# How do I stop a while loop with a button - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, while-loop

Hello guys I'm looking for a solution for this program:

```
var i = 0;
function timer(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
$w.onReady(function () {
    while (i === 0) {
        dosomething();
        timer(1000);
    }
});

export function button5_click(event) {
    i = 1;
}
```

My question is how can I stop this while with that button function?

Comment: You can't do that. A function can only be stopped with a `return` or an error.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`?

Comment: No asynchronous effect can stop an infinite synchronous loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this way!

```js
var flag = true;

let i = 0;
function loopFunc() {
    if (flag == true){
    i++;
        console.log( `Do something here ${i}` );
        setTimeout(loopFunc, 100);
    }
}

loopFunc();

function stop(){
    flag = false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stop();">Stop Loop</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a boolean which is checked if true in the while loop and if it true, the while loop will return. Add in an event listener to make that boolean true on click for the button. Don't forget to make the boolean false at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, you could do this

```
var stopLoop = false; // Add this to your code
var i = 0;
function timer(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
$w.onReady(function () {
    while (i === 0) {
        if(stopLoop) break;
        dosomething();
        timer(1000);
    }
});

export function button5_click(event) {
    stopLoop = true; // add this to your code
    i = 1; // You can comment this out
}
```